# Using conditionals to display elements of a view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, view

I'm using Ruby on Rails and I want to display a drop down list in a view, but only if items in the list exist.  What is a good way to check for the presence of at least one instance of a model, and then display in the view based on this condition?

I was thinking of using an if statement such as:

```
if firstmodel.secondmodels
```

. . html stuff

But I think the empty array doesn't stop evaluate to false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like this in your view:

```
<% if @items.any? %>
  <!-- drop down list here -->
<% else %>
  <div>No items :-(</div>
<% end %>
```

Generally you should try to keep logic out of your view, but I think in this simple case there are not many alternatives (?)

If there are too many `if else` like that your view, well... you could maybe check for this in your controller and render another view altogether, like:

```
# render no_content.html.erb if there are no items,
# default template file otherwise
render "no_content" unless @items.any?
# or:
render "no_content" if @items.empty?
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your example above, you can see if an array is empty by doing `empty?`.

```
if firstmodel.secondmodels.empty?
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need something like that:

```
<% if firstmodel.secondmodels.empty? %>
  <p>Stuff</p>
<% else %>
  <p>Other Stuff</p>
<% end %>
```

Of if you are using HAML:

```
- if firstmodel.secondmodels.empty?
  %p Stuff
- else %>
  %p Other Stuff
```